# How to hyperlink correctly

Tags: excel, vba, hyperlink

[image: Hyperlink Issue]

```
Sub GoToPCell()

Dim i As Long, j As Integer
Dim PCell As String
Dim lastrow As Long
Dim rng As Range

With Sheet1.Range("A:A")
If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Cells) <> 0 Then
Set rng = .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, 1)
Set rng = rng.Areas(rng.Areas.Count)
lastrow = rng.Cells(rng.Cells.Count).Row
End If
End With

For i = 2 To lastrow

If Not IsEmpty(Cells(i, "CT").End(xlToRight)) Then
PCell = Cells(i, "CT").End(xlToRight).Address
ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Cells(i, 2), Address:="", SubAddress:="'" & Sheet1.Name & "'!" & PCell
End If

Next i

End Sub
```

Would like to leave the blank cell on the left without creating a blue hyperlink named the current worksheet.

Comment: Use `IsEmpty` to check for this.

Comment: @BigBen Can you specify how to include IsEmpty? I assume using If statement?

Comment: `If Not IsEmpty(Cells(i, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft)) Then`.

Comment: @BigBen Hi BigBen, not sure if you will see this. I applied IsEmpty but it stayed the same: PCell = Cells(i, "CT").End(xlToRight).Address
If Not IsEmpty(PCell) Then...                          The code still changes the blank cells to the name of the worksheet. Do you have other suggestions? Thank you.

Comment: Don't call `IsEmpty` on a String

Comment: BigBen, I did (for the big worksheet): If Not IsEmpty(Cells(i, "CT").End(xlToRight).Address) Then     and 'The Reference isnt' valid' msgbox pops up when I click the hyperlink. How do I adjust this? I defined PCell as long, by the way. Thank you.

Comment: `Range.Address` returns a `String`. You don't want `.Address` inside an `IsEmpty` check.

Comment: Got it. I will post the new code as an answer to this OP. It still produces msgbox problem with references.

Comment: Got it, sorry. Just edited the OP.

Comment: You're still trying to use `PCell` within the hyperlink, but there's no line `PCell = ...`.

Comment: You're right. What do I replace PCell with, within the hyperlink? I'm confused..

Comment: Add a new line: `PCell = Cells(i, "CT").End(xlToRight).Address`, after the `If Not IsEmpty(Cells(i, "CT").End(xlToRight)) Then`.

Comment: Thank you, it works as before. The code still edits the blank cell with the blue hyperlink named the current worksheet. Other nonempty hyperlinks (x) work all right.

Comment: Can you [edit] your question with the code you are using now?

Comment: Yes, just posted the full code. Thank you.